# Where do the input_ids, input_mask, and segment_ids variables come from in a BERT model?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model

I'm trying to work through the Google BERT tutorial in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb), and am having a hard time following some of its steps.

Specifically, there is a function called `create_model` which reads like this:

```
def create_model(is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, labels,
             num_labels):
"""Creates a classification model."""

bert_module = hub.Module(
  BERT_MODEL_HUB,
  trainable=True)
bert_inputs = dict(
  input_ids=input_ids,
  input_mask=input_mask,
  segment_ids=segment_ids)
bert_outputs = bert_module(
  inputs=bert_inputs,
  signature="tokens",
  as_dict=True)

# Use "pooled_output" for classification tasks on an entire sentence.
# Use "sequence_outputs" for token-level output.
output_layer = bert_outputs["pooled_output"]

hidden_size = output_layer.shape[-1].value

# Create our own layer to tune for politeness data.
output_weights = tf.get_variable(
  "output_weights", [num_labels, hidden_size],
  initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))

output_bias = tf.get_variable(
  "output_bias", [num_labels], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

with tf.variable_scope("loss"):

# Dropout helps prevent overfitting
output_layer = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer, keep_prob=0.9)

logits = tf.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)
log_probs = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=-1)

# Convert labels into one-hot encoding
one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_labels, dtype=tf.float32)

predicted_labels = tf.squeeze(tf.argmax(log_probs, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32))
# If we're predicting, we want predicted labels and the probabiltiies.
if is_predicting:
  return (predicted_labels, log_probs)

# If we're train/eval, compute loss between predicted and actual label
per_example_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels * log_probs, axis=-1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_example_loss)
return (loss, predicted_labels, log_probs)
```

This would be fine, but when I look for where the `create_model` function is called in the notebook, the origin of the `input_ids`, `input_mask` and `segment_ids` arguments is not clear to me.

This is where the function is referenced later on in the notebook:

```
def model_fn_builder(num_labels, learning_rate, num_train_steps,
                 num_warmup_steps):
"""Returns `model_fn` closure for TPUEstimator."""
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
"""The `model_fn` for TPUEstimator."""

input_ids = features["input_ids"]
input_mask = features["input_mask"]
segment_ids = features["segment_ids"]
label_ids = features["label_ids"]

is_predicting = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT)

# TRAIN and EVAL
if not is_predicting:

  (loss, predicted_labels, log_probs) = create_model(
    is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids, num_labels)
```

The problem here is that the `features` argument is not listed as an argument in the parent function, and it's not defined anywhere else in the notebook.  So I'm not sure why it works, and even more importantly, I'm not sure what things like `features['input_ids']` are supposed to represent.  Without this being clear to me, it'll be difficult to make sense of what BERT actually does.

Thank you for your help.